# Big Sur terminal sometimes 5-second lag, 16in intel macbook pro

Tags: terminal, keyboard, big-sur

**update 5** issue seems to still be happening for another user (see comment in answer below) under macOS 11.2.3.

**update 4** Looks like this issue in terminal is no longer happening after updating to 11.2.3. However, there's now a similar issue in Google Chrome where having multiple tabs open and then clicking a tab does nothing, but then moving the cursor will go to that tab (the expected behavior is obviously to go the tab immediately upon clicking the tab). The "Battery" settings under System Preferences now has a checkbox to enable/disable discrete graphics switching (not sure if it was there before) but disabling switching causes the Chrome tab problem to go away.

**update 3** This just happened to me again when my macbook was at 100% battery, and plugged in. Is it possible that it's not due to the graphics switching?

**Update 2** Looks like this is a known bug with the hybrid graphics of my MBP, as the answer below points out. [Here's another thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-16-inch-freeze-issue-automatic-graphics-switching.2217231/). Interestingly, I haven't noticed any issues in other apps like Chrome or Safari that much, just in Terminal.

**Update** I notice that the lag seems to happen only when running on battery. Additionally, I've observed in even when not pressing return, for example when using Vim and just navigating around with `hjkl`, sometimes a single keypress would seem to not register, but then the second press would "flush" of them, or alternatively waiting about 5 seconds will "flush" the first press.

**original**

I'm using the default terminal in Big Sur using 2019 16 inch macbook pro. I'm on a clean install, with no changed settings or installed programs. Default shell settings.

Sometimes (maybe once every 15 min or so) when I input a command in terminal (e.g. `ls` or `cd ~/Documents`), and when I hit Return on my keyboard, the terminal seems to do nothing. If I press any key again, then the Return "goes through", along with the second key I pressed. Alternatively, if I just wait 5 seconds, the Return "goes through", and everything is fine.

Has anyone else noticed this terminal lag?

Comment: No shell config besides what Apple provides to a new user account?

Comment: yes, no shell config changes.

Comment: i have a 2020 intel imac running Big Sur and i get instant response using both the Terminal app and iterm 2.  I use unix a lot and have not noticed a delay.

Comment: Are you running anything else at the same time?

Comment: I'm just running safari and finder, nothing else. I actually noticed this problem on my previous install of Big Sur (was happening for several weeks, about once every 15 min, at unpredictable times, and not consistently reproducible), so I did a clean install this morning, and immediately started noticing the same thing.

To clarify, I get instant response about 95% of the time. The other few percent I get lag like this. It happens both in the default `zsh` as well as other REPL prompts, like `python3` or `ghci`.

Comment: @jmh I'm guessing imac does not swap between integrated and discrete graphics? (Nash's answer below seems to make sense, since I realized that my issue only happens when my 16-in pro [which has integrated and discrete graphics] runs on battery, not while plugged in)

Comment: Same here on a 16-inch, 2019 MB Pro, 11.3.1. Keystrokes sometimes don't register immediately - have to either wait 5 seconds or press another key to "flush" it. Have the issue in Terminal, Alacritty, iTerm2. Happens when plugged in or on battery.

Comment: I'm having same issue on MBP 16 2019. It occurs when typing in terminal - the last typed symbol is not shown in prompt only if you wait for 5-6 second or hit another key or move cursor with touchpad. Looks like it needs any action then screen redraw happens. The problem goes away when graphics is switched to discrete

Comment: Yeah, same thing here. Same laptop (MBP 16 2019), same OS (11.6.6), same bug. Is there a solution (other than upgrading the OS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: confirmed issue still happens as of macOS 11.2 RC3**

Exact same behavior here on a 16" 2019 MBP, starting from when I updated to macOS 11.0 and still occurring as of 11.2 beta 2.

Able to reproduce "on demand" by typing "ls" repeatedly in both iTerm2 as well as the built in terminal.app.

Root cause seems to be the Intel graphics driver, as disabling graphics switching or connecting an external monitor (which forces discrete graphics) eliminates the issue at the cost of battery life.

Comment: interesting; I'm not able to reproduce on demand like that. For me it happens every once in a while, but usually if I repeatedly type `ls`, it responds instantly.

How do you disable graphics switching? I looked for "energy saver" in preferences, but it's not there.

Comment: It's been moved to under "battery"

Comment: I just observed this issue happening when plugged in. Does that mean it's not caused by graphics switching? Surely when plugged in, the macbook would just stick to discrete graphics, right?

Comment: Plugging power in does *not* cause the Mac to switch to using discrete graphics. Also, you can confirm what GPU is being used at a given time by opening up activity monitor, selecting the energy tab and looking along the bottom. Keep in mind that the frequent refresh of the activity monitor window might actually prevent the issue from occurring as long as it is visible as well.

Comment: re: "frequent refresh of activity monitor may actually prevent the issue": does this qualify as a hacky workaround? Are there any drawbacks (e.g. decreased battery) of just opening activity monitor whenever I want to use terminal, just to prevent this annoying lag?

Comment: update: I just experienced the terminal lag **with** the energy tab in Activity monitor open, so this is definitely not a guaranteed workaround

Comment: this issue seems to no longer be happening for me with 11.2.3; terminal is a lot snappier and no lagging. Does it appear to be better for you now?

Comment: Unchanged, still able to reproduce readily under in the built-in terminal under 11.2.3

Comment: However, I cannot seem to reproduce the issue in iTerm2 as long as GPU rendering is enabled. Therefore, this might be a better workaround than disabling GFX switching altogether.

Comment: 2019 16 MBP with 11.4 issue is still present. Any workaround except forcing discrete graphics?

Comment: Yeah, same thing here. Same laptop (MBP 16 2019), same OS (11.6.6), same bug. Is there a solution (other than upgrading the OS)?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue on a 2019 16-inch MacBook Pro running Ventura 13.4.1.

The issue is caused by automatic graphics switching. I noticed that the issue was present only when *not* connected to an external monitor; using the built-in keyboard and monitor.

Go to System Settings -> Battery -> Options and disable automatic graphics switching to resolve the intermittent keyboard delay in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this is still an issue on Sonoma (14.0) using a 16" 2019 MacBook Pro. I observed it anytime I was in Terminal.app regardless of which host I was logged in to. It happened when I was working locally and when I had SSH'd into another host.

As others have noted, the resolution appears to be: **System Settings** > **Battery** > **Options** > **Disable Automatic Graphics Switching**.

Answer (score -2):

I rebooted my mac and that fixed the issue

Comment: I highly doubt this. Either yours is an entirely different issue, or it's the same as mine but the reboot did not actually solve it

Comment: Probably a different issue indeed, but worth the try for the people who got here.